# SQL Server CTE query not getting desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have table with few columns & I am using a CTE to get data in a hierarchical order in sorted manner:

```
Cat 1
--item X1
--item X2
Cat 2
Cat 3
Cat 4
cat 5
--item A1
--item A2
Cat 6
```

Table data:

```
ID  LanguageID  Name        ParentID    Active
----------------------------------------------
1   1           Cat 1       0           1
2   1           item X1     1           1
3   1           item X2     1           1
4   1           cat 2       0           1
5   1           cat 3       0           0
6   1           cat 4       0           1
7   1           cat 5       0           1
8   1           item A1     7           1
9   1           item A2     7           0
10  1           cat 6       0           1
```

CTE query:

```
WITH CTE (ID, ParentID, Name, LanguageID, Active, Depth, SortCol) AS  
( 
    SELECT 
        ID, ParentID, Name, LanguageID, Active, 0, 
        CAST(ID AS varbinary(max)) 
    FROM 
        Project 
    WHERE 
        ParentID = 0 AND  Active = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        d.ID, d.ParentID, d.Name, p.LanguageID, p.Active, p.Depth + 1, 
        CAST(SortCol + CAST(d.ID AS binary(4)) AS varbinary(max)) 
    FROM 
        Project AS d 
    JOIN 
        CTE AS p ON d.ParentID = p.ID
    WHERE 
        p.Active = 1
) 
SELECT 
    ID, ParentID, Name, LanguageID, Active, Depth, 
    REPLICATE('&nbsp;&nbsp;', Depth) + Name as HName 
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE 
    LanguageID = 1 AND  Active = 1
ORDER BY 
    Name
```

Above query hides the parent category but not the child items.

Second I am only able to order parent category in name but not the **child items**.

Expected output should be:

```
Cat 1
--item X1
--item X2
Cat 2
Cat 4
cat 5
--item A1
Cat 6
```

UPDATE: Just to mention I am not showing the all the columns of CTE query in above output below is the complete output of query

```
ID  ParentID    Name        LanguageID  Active  Depth   HName
------------------------------------------------------------------
1      0        Cat 1           1           1       0   Cat 1
4      1        item X1         1           1       0   item X1
7      1        item X2         1           1       0   item X2
8      0        cat 2           1           1       1   cat 2
9      0        cat 4           1           1       1   cat 4
10     0        cat 5           1           1       0   cat 5
3      7        item A1         1           1       1   item A1
2      7        item A2         1           1       1   item A2
6      0        cat 6           1           1       0   cat 6
```

Comment: To filter out the `item A2` record you need to use `WHERE d.Active = 1` instead of `WHERE p.Active = 1`

Comment: Thanks, I know i was making some mistake which i was not able to see. Thanks for pointing it out. Please put it is an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

you can use self join here. see the below query

```
select p.Name, c.Name,c.Active,c.Id,c.LanguageID
From Project c left outer join Project p
where c.ParentId = p.Id
```